# Conditional Logic within SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently combining two tables through a UNION ALL query and performing SUM and GROUP BY operations on the result. Everything is working as expected, but I have a unique requirement which I can't seem to figure out how to implement.
My aim is to write SQL that says "when DEV_AGE column is >= 12 set the REVENUE value to what it would be if this column was 12". I provide the code below as I know this description can be a bit confusing:

REVENUE table:

```
ACC_YR    DEV_AGE   STATE   REVENUE LOSS
2012        3         MA     4000    0
2012        6         MA     8000    0
2012        9         MA     12000   0
2012        12        MA     16000   0
```

LOSS table:

```
ACC_YR    DEV_AGE   STATE   REVENUE LOSS
2012        3         MA     0       2000
2012        6         MA     0       7000
2012        9         MA     0       9000
2012        12        MA     0       10000
2012        15        MA     0       14000
2012        18        MA     0       14000
2012        21        MA     0       14000
2012        24        MA     0       15000
2012        27        MA     0       17000
```

Table after UNION ALL, GROUP BY, SUM:

```
ACC_YR    DEV_AGE   STATE   REVENUE LOSS
2012        3         MA     4000    2000
2012        6         MA     8000    7000
2012        9         MA     12000   9000
2012        12        MA     16000   10000
2012        15        MA     0       14000
2012        18        MA     0       14000
2012        21        MA     0       14000
2012        24        MA     0       15000
2012        27        MA     0       17000
```

What I WANT to accomplish:

```
ACC_YR    DEV_AGE   STATE   REVENUE LOSS
2012        3         MA     4000    2000
2012        6         MA     8000    7000
2012        9         MA     12000   9000
2012        12        MA     16000   10000
2012        15        MA     16000   14000
2012        18        MA     16000   14000
2012        21        MA     16000   14000
2012        24        MA     16000   15000
2012        27        MA     16000   17000
```

In other words, my REVENUE stops developing at a DEV_AGE of 12 (there are no rows in the REVENUE table beyond a DEV_AGE of 12), but I want every DEV_AGE beyond 12 to equal what the REVENUE was at 12 in the final table.

Comment: whats your code for the revenue field in the output table?

Comment: @Matt, currently it's simply SUM(REVENUE) as I didn't even know where to begin with this requirement.

Comment: easily done with a case when, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses window functions to calculate the revenue for age 12 and then logic to assign it:

```
select acc_yr, dev_age, state,
       (case when dev_age > 12 then rev12 else revenue end) as revenue, loss
from (select l.acc_yr, l.dev_age, l.state, r.revenue, l.loss,
             max(case when l.dev_age = 12 then r.revenue end) over (partition by l.acc_yr, l.state) as rev12
      from loss l left join
           revenue r
           on l.acc_yr = r.acc_yr and l.dev_age = r.dev_age and l.state = dev.state
     ) lr;
```

Comment: If I wanted to apply this logic to the final (combined) table rather than messing with the joins would the below code work: `SELECT acc_yr, dev_age, state, (case when dev_age > 12 then rev12 else revenue end) as revenue, loss
FROM (select acc_yr, dev_age, state, revenue, loss, max(case when dev_age = 12 then revenue end) over
     (partition by acc_yr, state) as rev12 from combined)`